# Tesnsor flow Import Error in my windows 7

Tags: python, tensorflow

Whenever I run the following code:

```
'import tensorflow'
```

I get the following error:

'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 54, in preload_check
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Could not find the DLL(s) 'msvcp140.dll or msvcp140_1.dll'. TensorFlow requires that these DLLs be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. You may install these DLLs by downloading "Microsoft C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019" for your platform from this URL: https://support.microsoft.com/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads
'
```

Comment: Then just install the DLLs from the link in the error.

Answer (score 0):

You issue can be resolved once you installed the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017, and 2019. Starting with the TensorFlow 2.1.0 version, the `msvcp140_1.dll` file is required.

For more details you can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip).